# popviewcontroller does nothing, doesn't work

Tags: objective-c, ios5, uipopovercontroller, back-button, xcode4.4

I'm trying to go back into a ViewController using popoverviewcontroller, but nothing happens. 
First, I'm loading the first ViewController, in the AppDelegate, with this code:

```
UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.welcomeMenu];
nav.navigationBarHidden = YES;
self.window.rootViewController = nav;
nav = nil;
```

The navigationBar is hidden because I need it in that way 
In this ViewController, I'm showing a menu with buttons, then, to show another ViewController, I'm using this code:

```
SecondViewController *secView = [[SecondViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];

[UIView  beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.75];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:secView animated:NO];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight forView:self.navigationController.view cache:NO];
[UIView commitAnimations];
secView = nil;
```

And the SecondViewController loads (but the rotation doesn't work)... 
My SecondViewController adds in code a SplitViewController (with a NavigationController for the Table on the left, and another NavigationController for another table on the right) 
Then, in the SecondViewController, I'm adding manually a button to go back, using this code:

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
```

but nothing happens...
When I print self.navigationController, the output is (null), so I guess this is the problem, but why my self.navigationController is null? And What I need to do to pop correctly?
If I don't hide the navigationBar in the AppDelegate code, the backButton that appears automatically works fine, but when I want to do it, manually, does not work...

Comment: Try changing bundle:nil to bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot load a split view controller from your SecondViewController.

See [Split View Controllers](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerCatalog/Chapters/SplitViewControllers.html):

> A split view controller must always be the root of any interface you
>   create. In other words, you must always install the view from a
>   UISplitViewController object as the root view of your application’s
>   window. The panes of your split view interface may then contain
>   navigation controllers, tab bar controllers, or any other type of view
>   controller you need to implement your interface. Split view
>   controllers cannot be presented modally.

Comment: So I need to delete SecondViewController, declare and load SplitViewController in my MainViewController, and add the SplitViewController in one NavigationController?

Comment: No, the split view controller can only be the root of ALL OTHER view controllers. You can not use it in a navigation controller.

Comment: Oh, ok. Now I understand... I guess I'm going to need to change my paradigm. Thank you very much... When I call my SplitViewController from my MainViewController, changing "self.window.rootViewController", can I add an animation?

Comment: @user1600801: Yes probably. There are some open source replacements for UISplitViewController that are less restricted, but I have no practical experience with these.

Comment: Thank you very much... Now I call the SplitViewController directly, but I need to find who to add an animation to the transition and who to go back to MainViewController

Answer (score 0):

You never added SecondViewController to the navigation controller's viewControllers, that's why self.navigationController logs null, so just update the viewControllers array with your new controller.

Comment: So the line [self.navigationController pushViewController:secView animated:NO]; does not do that?

Comment: It is added, because after [self.navigationController pushViewController:secView animated:NO], I print [self.navigationController.viewControllers count] and the output is 2. Still, I add the ViewController manually, the output is also 2. Then, when I want to pop the ViewController, the output is 0 and self.navigationController is (null)

Comment: Sorry, I was looking at the popViewController message and didn't notice your push line -- yes that push should add the view controller to the stack. So, I'm not sure why self.navigationController is logging as null.

Comment: Oh, ok. It seems a little rare that problem... Thank you